# Equating strings with true in if

Tags: javascript

Probably I am confused or something but I am not able to understand this silly scenario.

```js
if("true"){
  console.log("Above is true");
}
else{
  console.log("Above is false");
}
```

In the above case the console is nicely printing `Above is true`. Which makes total sense. But when I am doing:

```js
if("true" == true){
  console.log("Above is true");
}
else{
  console.log("Above is false");
}
```

I am seeing that `Above is false` is getting printed in the console.

I am using a loose equality operator here and even after coercion `true` will convert to `"true"` so it should print `Above is true` but is not. What am I missing?

Comment: "true" is string and true is a boolean value so those are not equal

Comment: @JayShankarGupta but I am using loose equality operator here. Just like `0 == false` is true but `0 === false` is not.

Comment: You just reminded me why I don't use javascript :)

Comment: @Striped sorry I did not understand your comment.

Comment: @void he wanted to say that _any_ string is truthy

Comment: ("aString" !== undefined) == true

Comment: @Striped No. `""` is also a string, and it is also `!== undefined` but `if("")` is false. `false, "", 0, NaN, null, undefined` these are the falsy values. **everything else** will be considered truthy. This has nothing to do with comparison to `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out this article https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

```
//EQUALITY CHECK...
"true" == true; 
//HOW IT WORKS...
//boolean is converted using toNumber
"true" == 1;
//string is converted using toNumber
NaN == 1; //false!
```

Comment: `//string is converted using toNumber` - Nope... -> [11.9.3.7](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) (11.9.3.5 is not fulfilled)

Answer (score 0):

"If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted to 1 if it is true and +0 if it is false."

```
true == "true"; //false
true == "1"; //true
false == "false"; //false
false == ""; //true
false == "0"; //true
```

[Further readings on here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)